# Change Cell formatting based on value

Tags: excel, vba

How do I automatically format a cell as I enter a value?

I divided the numbers into 3 categories: percentages, small numbers (-1000 - 1000), and large numbers.

I want percentages to be displayed with 2 decimals and the % sign.
Small numbers with 2 decimals as well.
And large numbers rounded to nearest integer, with thousands separators.

I want the code to reformat the cell if the cell value changes. For instance, if I change a cell with value "50,000", to 60%, then, it should be displayed as "60.00%".

Code I have so far applies formatting on existing cell values.

```vb
Sub myNumberFormat()

Dim cel As Range
Dim selectedRange As Range

Set selectedRange = Selection

For Each cel In selectedRange.Cells
    If Not CStr(cel.Text) Like "*%*" Then
    
        If Not IsEmpty(cel) Then
            If cel.Value < 1000 And cel.Value > -1000 Then
                cel.NumberFormat = "_(#,##0.00_);_(-#,##0.00_);_(""-""??_)"
            Else
                cel.NumberFormat = "_(#,##0_);_((#,##0);_(""-""??_)"
            End If
            
        End If
        
    Else
        cel.NumberFormat = "0.00%"
    End If
    
Next cel
End Sub
```

Comment: Look into Worksheet_Change events

Answer (score 0):

### A Worksheet Change: Apply Cell Formatting

- This is a simple example for a single column, in this particular case, the range from `A2` to the bottom-most cell in column `A`. But you can choose any reasonable cell address. In whatever cell you manually change (enter, copy/paste, or write using VBA) its value, the cell will be formatted according to your 'rearranged' procedure `ApplyMySpecialNumberFormat`.
- Note that this works automatically, just copy the codes to the appropriate modules and start entering data into the cells of the range to see it work.

**Sheet Module e.g. `Sheet1`**

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const FirstCellAddress As String = "A2" ' adjust to any reasonable cell
    
    ' Reference the source column range e.g. 'A2:ALastWorksheetRow'.
    Dim srg As Range '
    With Me.Range(FirstCellAddress)
        Set srg = .Resize(Me.Rows.Count - .Row + 1)
    End With
    
    ' Reference the cells of the source range that have changed.
    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = Intersect(srg, Target)
    If irg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no source range cells changed; exit
    
    ' At least one cell was changed:
    ApplyMySpecialNumberFormat irg
    
End Sub
```

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ApplyMySpecialNumberFormat(ByVal rg As Range)

    Dim cel As Range

    For Each cel In rg.Cells
        If CStr(cel.Text) Like "*%*" Then
            cel.NumberFormat = "0.00%"
        Else
            If VarType(cel) = vbDouble Then ' is a number
                If cel.Value < 1000 And cel.Value > -1000 Then
                    cel.NumberFormat = "_(#,##0.00_);_(-#,##0.00_);_(""-""??_)"
                Else
                    cel.NumberFormat = "_(#,##0_);_((#,##0);_(""-""??_)"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next cel

End Sub
```

Comment: what does the 'define constants' and 'reference source column range' do?