# For and IF mixed to format cells

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, if-statement

Regrettably, I cannot get this to work.  Parts of it did, but now not so much.
I based it off of this post:

[Change Cell formatting based on value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72849414/change-cell-formatting-based-on-value)

The goal:

- After entering data in a cell

  - the script is looking to see if it is a date (ISDATE)
- Then if it is a date, it needs to compare it to other cells with dates

  - A3 is now(); v3 is A3+3; W3 is A3+10; X3 is A3+20

    - Each of the formula cells V3,W3,X3 were inserted with =TEXT(A3+x,"m/d/yyyy") to keep formatting the same(if this mattered)
- Then I added the Else - to answer the FALSE of the ISDATE and the format of that criteria

So, here it is:

**NOTE: This part works (I think)**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    ' Define constants.
    Const FirstCellAddress As String = "G5" 'first cell to start looking to format
    
    ' Reference the source column range e.g. 'A2:ALastWorksheetRow'.
    Dim srg As Range
    With Me.Range(FirstCellAddress)
        Set srg = .Resize(Me.Rows.Count - .Row + 1)
    End With
    
    ' Reference the cells of the source range that have changed.
    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = Intersect(srg, Target)
    If irg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no cells changed so exit
    
    ' At least one cell was changed:
    ApplyWarningFormat irg

End Sub
```

**NOTE: This section is NOT working**

```
Sub ApplyWarningFormat(ByVal rg As Range)

    Dim cel As Range
        
    For Each cel In rg.Cells
        If IsDate(cel.Text) Then
            If cel.Text < Range("A3").Text Then
                cel.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 80, 80)
                
            If cel.Text < Range("V3").Text Then
                cel.Interior.Color = RGB(210, 135, 25)
                
            If cel.Text < Range("W3").Text Then
                cel.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 100)
                
            If cel.Text < Range("X3").Text Then
                cel.Interior.Color = RGB(145, 205, 80)
                
            Else: cel.Interior.Color = RGB(195, 225, 245)
         
        End If
            
    Next cel

End Sub
```

Multiple questions on StackOverflow and edit/test/edit/test

Comment: It'd likely be better if instead of using `TEXT` in `=TEXT(A3+x,"m/d/yyyy")`, you just used `=A3+x` and then applied the m/d/yyy *format* to the cell. Once you've used `TEXT`, you can no longer do math with the dates in a straightforward manner. Btw you can use conditional formatting for this, no need for VBA.

Comment: thanks @BigBen 
I had tried the conditional, but it almost seemed more complicated.  I'll try that again.  And the issue was DATE vs TEXT.   But let me try that some more.
Still for my own learning, I would like see if this code can be fixed.

Comment: Change `If cel.Text < Range("A3").Text Then` to `If CDate(cel.Value) < Range("A3").Value Then` and similarly for the other lines. Basically, you need to convert `cell.Value` to a Date.

Answer (score 0):

### Compare Dates in a Loop

- If you're allowed to perform the 'date calculations' in the code and keep the formulas as 'decor':

```vb
Sub ApplyWarningFormat(ByVal rg As Range)

    Dim CompareDate As Date: CompareDate rg.Worksheet.Range("A3").Value
    
    Dim cell As Range, CellDate As Variant
    
    For Each cell In rg.Cells
        
        CellDate = cell.Value
        
        If IsDate(CellDate) Then
            Select Case CellDate
                Case Is < CompareDate
                    cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 80, 80)
                Case Is < CompareDate + 3
                    cell.Interior.Color = RGB(210, 135, 25)
                Case Is < CompareDate + 10
                    cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 100)
                Case Is < CompareDate + 20
                    cell.Interior.Color = RGB(145, 205, 80)
                Case Else
                    cell.Interior.Color = RGB(195, 225, 245)
            End Select
        End If
            
    Next cell

End Sub
```